# Firebase Storage and PhoneGap - Sending a file that's in an Img element

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, phonegap

Very new to Firebase and I'm trying to do what seems like a simple task - upload a file to Firebase from my PhoneGap HTML/JS app. The image is in an Img element on the page, and when a user taps the upload button I'm trying to capture the data I need from the file that's in the element but I'm not having much luck.

I'm basing my attempt off this Firecast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU with the difference being I'm not using a file picker. All the examples I've found use file pickers so I'm not sure how to deal with a file that's already on the page. I get this error when it gets to storageRef.put():

```
{t: "storage/invalid-argument", e: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.", n: null, r: "FirebaseError"}
```

So I know I'm not passing what Firebase needs, but that's as far as I've got.

This is my HTML:

```
<img class='center' id="myImage" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/********e.appspot.com/o/images%2F2014%20(39).JPG?alt=media&token=9c3d1613-c880-4437-abf9-f59bbcdc885bG">

<label class="center">Choose a category for the photo: 
        <select class="center" id="categories"></select>
</label>

<label class="">
        <button class="button button-block button-balanced padding" id="uploadpicture">Upload Photo</button>
</label>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

  // Initialize Firebase
          var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyCN***********POk",
            authDomain: "***-storage.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://****oto-storage.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "***w-photo-storage",
            storageBucket: "*****hoto-storage.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "2*****4314287"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);

          function uploadImage(){

            var img_file = document.getElementById("myImage");
            var d = new Date();
            var dateString = d.toISOString();

            img_file.name = dateString;

            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('photowPhotos/' + img_file.name);

            var task = storageRef.put(img_file);

            task.on('state_changed',
                function error(err){
                    alert(err);
                },

                function complete(){
                    alert("Upload successful!")
                }
                );
          }

          $('#uploadpicture').on('click', uploadImage);
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, here is the code.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
 quality: quality,
 sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
 destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 targetWidth: imageSize,
 targetHeight: imageSize
});

function onSuccess(imageData) {

var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

var getFileBlob = function(url, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        cb(xhr.response);
    });
    xhr.send();
};

var blobToFile = function(blob, name) {
    blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    blob.name = name;
    return blob;
};

var getFileObject = function(filePathOrUrl, cb) {
    getFileBlob(filePathOrUrl, function(blob) {
        cb(blobToFile(blob, 'test.jpg'));
    });
};

getFileObject(imageData, function(fileObject) {
    var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/test.jpg').put(fileObject);

    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }, function() {
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log(downloadURL);
        // handle image here
    });
});

}
```